# Picasso doesn't seem to use the memoryCache I give it

Tags: android, picasso

In a project I'm working on (named Boxsetter) I'm trying to get Picasso to use a disk cache I've created (BoxsetterImageCache, implementing the Cache interface):

```
new Picasso.Builder(activity)
   .memoryCache(new BoxsetterImageCache(activity))
   .build()
   .with(activity)
   .load(be.getImg())
   .placeholder(R.drawable.boxsetter2)
   .into(imageView);
```

Through logging I can see the BoxsetterImageCache instance get created. However, no -get- or -set-, or any other method, is called on the BoxsetterImageCache instance after that (which I can tell through the absence of copious logs firing, and no files being created).

The rest of Picasso is working fine: the placeholder is being placed in the ImageView and then happily replaced by images accessed over http. However, it doesn't seem to be calling methods on the cache.

Any ideas as to why that might be? Is there something wrong with this implementation?

Cheers

Nic

BoxsetterImageCache:

```
package com.boxsetter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import com.squareup.picasso.Cache;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

/**
 * Created by nic.ford on 27/04/15.
 */
public class BoxsetterImageCache implements Cache {

    private String filesDir;

    public BoxsetterImageCache(BoxsetterActivity ba) {
        Log.d("BSBIC", "BIC created"); // THIS LOG IS SEEN
        this.filesDir = ba.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap get(String key) {
        File file = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/" + key);

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "get() File on path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        File file = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/" + key);

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "set() File on path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        File dir = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/");

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "size() File on path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());

        int len = 0;

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            len += file.length();
        }

        return len;
    }

    @Override
    public int maxSize() {
        File file = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/");

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "maxSize() File on path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        return (int)file.getFreeSpace();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        File dir = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/");

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "clear() File on path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearKeyUri(String keyPrefix) {
        File dir = new File(filesDir + "/bmps/");

        // THIS LOG IS NEVER SEEN
        Log.d("BSBIC", "clearKeyUri() File on path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().startsWith(keyPrefix)) file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You are making a new instance of your cache every single time there.  Don't.  See #2.
2) You should use Picasso's single instance.  Do NOT build a new Picasso for every load.  That defeats the purpose.
3) You are doing file I/O in that cache which is run on the main thread!  Don't do it.

Comment: You're right - but that's only because I've simplified this down to show the problem. For production, and indeed usually while testing, I create a single instance: the same problem occurs.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using setSingletonInstance()?

Comment: 2) I'm not using Picasso's single instance because if I do I can't create my own cache - however, I (usually) create a single instance of *a* Picasso, with my own cache - see (1); 3) Again, this is to demonstrate the problem rather than to go to production - if I can get the caching to work, I can make it more sophisticated later; at the moment, it needs to be as simple as possible in order to debug.

Comment: setSingletonInstance() - Ah! No, I'm not! Can you point me to the documentation for that? I've not found it.

Comment: When it's working, however, I create a class variable to hold a single Picasso instance, and use that all the time - is setSingletonInstance() still needed that case?

Comment: Google the API.  I just put my own Picasso into Picasso.setSingletonInstance into my Application's onCreate(), but you can put it anywhere BEFORE you call .with()

Comment: setSingletonInstance is what you should use if you want to use Picasso.with(Context context) to get your Picasso instance.  You could make your own singleton instance, but it's easier to use Picasso.with()

Comment: Aha! Just found the docs for setSingletonInstance() - I reckon that's it. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the issue here.  Also, please don't do file I/O on the main thread in a production app.  You're doing that with your cache in your question.  Just a note there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Nightly Nexus found the answer (for which, thanks).

I was creating my own Picasso instance with my disk cache, but then calling the `with(context)` method on it. `with(context)` always returns the Picasso singleton rather than the instance on which it was invoked, so I was immediately passing control away from my own instance.

Two options:

1. remove the `with(context)`, or
2. use `Picasso.setSingletonInstance(mypicasso)` to replace the existing singleton with my instance

I went for the former, which now works perfectly. So now I can refactor it a bit, and get rid of the main thread disk I/O.

Thanks!

Comment: with(Context) is a static method of Picasso.
If you already have a Picasso instance that you want to use, just use it.  :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer, and you'll get a badge.

Comment: Thanks - and for the static method info (of which I was unaware).